# Unity - Creating a UI list at runtime programmatically

Tags: c#, list, user-interface, unity-game-engine, populate

I have a scene where I should be able to select a 3D model from a list of items, which will then be loaded into the next scene. I want to generate the list of items programmatically, based on what is already stored in the local database. But I have problems getting the list of items to be displayed in the scene ...

So I have a class for the items:

```
[System.Serializable] public class Item { 
     public string ObjectGuid;
     public string Name;
     public string Description;
     public Sprite Icon;
     public Button.ButtonClickedEvent SelectObject;
}
```

A script for my scene, that contains a list of items and a method that I call to load the objects from the database:

```
public class ObjectSelectionScript : MonoBehaviour {
public List<Item> itemList;
public Transform contentPanel;

void LoadObjects() {
     StreamReader str = new StreamReader (Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + DataManager.LOCATION_XML_PATH);
     string result = str.ReadToEnd ();
     str.Close();
     var jo = SimpleJSON.JSON.Parse (result);

     if (jo ["Objects"] != null) {
         for (int i = 0; i < jo["Objects"].Count; i++) {
             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jo["Objects"][i]["FileGuid"])) {
                 Item newObject = new Item();
                 newObject.ObjectGuid = jo["Objects"][i]["ObjectGuid"];
                 newObject.Name = jo["Objects"][i]["Name"];
                 newObject.Description = jo["Objects"][i]["Description"];
                 //newObject.SelectObject = new Button.ButtonClickedEvent();
                 itemList.Add(newObject);
             }
         }
     } 
 }
```

A ModelObject class:

```
 public class ModelObject : MonoBehaviour {
     public Button button;
     public Text Name;
     public Text Description;
     public Image Icon;
 }
```

And a prefab ModelObjectPrefab that contains Name, Description, a Thumbnail, added to my assests folder.

The PopulateList() method is my problem. I can't get to instatiate the prefab and then create ModelObjects that I can throw in the contentPanel in the interface. This is my code:

```
void PopulateList()
{
     try {
         foreach (var item in itemList)
         {
             GameObject newModel = Instantiate(ModelObject) as GameObject;
             ModelObject myModelObject = newModel.GetComponent<ModelObject>();
             myModelObject.Name.text = item.Name;
             myModelObject.Description.text = item.IDescription;
             myModelObject.icon.sprite = item.Icon;
             myModelObject.button.onClick = item.selectObject;
             newModel.transform.SetParent(contentPanel);

         }

     } catch (System.Exception ex) {

     }
 }
```

I currently get null pointer on instantiate. I have tried Resources.Load, and variations of the Instatiate method, but I did not find a solution.

Can anyone give me a hint what is the problem? How should PopulateList() look like to get the items to the interface?

Comment: Try changing the name of your prefab. It matches the name of the class type and that is never a good thing.

Comment: tried that. still not working.

Comment: thx anyway. I just don't see what the problem is and any suggestion could work

Comment: Is the prefab not null? and does it contain a ModelObject component?

Comment: The prefab does not contain a ModelObject. It has a Name, Description and Image.

Comment: But  a prefab has to be a game object with the ModelObject attached to. Without this setup, Instantiate won't do and GetComponent will return null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note** for readers. "GUI" is no longer available in Unity.  Simply use the new UI system.  Example http://www.folio3.com/blog/creating-dynamic-scrollable-lists-with-new-unity-canvas-ui/

---

The only thing that did work was to create the whole GUI programmatically.
I created a `GUI.matrix` and added everything inside it. It did not look very good, so I spent a lot of time trying to make it look better and to be responsive on mobile devices, but in the end this was the only solution that worked.

Just as a quick reference for who ever might have the same issue, the solution has this structure:

```
public void OnGUI ()
{
var savedMatrix = GUI.matrix;
scrollPosition = GUI.BeginScrollView (new Rect (10f, 10f, Screen.width - 10f, Screen.height - 10f), scrollPosition, new Rect (10f, 10f, Screen.width - 10f, (_files.Count + 2) * 200f));
        if (Input.touchCount == 1) {
            Vector2 touchDelta2 = Input.GetTouch (0).deltaPosition;
            scrollPosition.y += touchDelta2.y;
        }
        var selected = GUILayout.SelectionGrid (gridInt, _files.ToArray (), 1, MyStyle);
        if (selected >= 0) {
            if (selected == 0) {
                if (selectedItem != null )
                    if (selectedItem.Parent != null)
                        selectedItem = selectedItem.Parent;
                else 
                    selectedItem = null;
            } else {
                SelectFolder (selected);
            }

            RefreshViewModel ();
        }
        GUI.EndScrollView ();
        GUI.matrix = savedMatrix;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the [`Instantiate()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) method should not be given a type (eg. `ModelObject`) as an argument. Rather, you should be passing it an object instance (in this case, your prefab `GameObject` "ModelObjectPrefab"). The documentation specifically indicates that it requires:

> An existing object that you want to make a copy of

Otherwise, you're probably going to get unexpected behaviour like this. In your code, we need to pass a reference to "ModelObjectPrefab" as an argument of the `Instantiate()` call. I would suggest modifying your class containing `PopulateList()` to look like:

```
// New variable to hold prefab object
public GameObject modelObjectPrefab;

// ...

void PopulateList()
{
     try {
         foreach (var item in itemList)
         {
             // Reference prefab variable instead of class type
             GameObject newModel = Instantiate(modelObjectPrefab) as GameObject;
             ModelObject myModelObject = newModel.GetComponent<ModelObject>();
             myModelObject.Name.text = item.Name;
             myModelObject.Description.text = item.IDescription;
             myModelObject.icon.sprite = item.Icon;
             myModelObject.button.onClick = item.selectObject;
             newModel.transform.SetParent(contentPanel);

         }

     } catch (System.Exception ex) {

     }
}
```

Then, in the Editor window, drag your prefab "ModelObjectPrefab" from the assets panel onto the new `Model Object Prefab` field in the script properties, to form the connection between the script and the prefab.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but I still get a null value for 'myModelObject' when I do a GetComponent<ModelObject>() ... I am absolutely clueless why this is happening.